# I asked a question while not using my username, now that I logged in I can't comment (I'm below 50 in reputation)

Tags: support, user-accounts

I made a mistake by posting a question while thinking I was logged in but in fact wasn't - [Have anyone found a good solution to Kant's dualistic approach to consciousness?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48131/have-anyone-found-a-good-solution-to-kants-dualistic-approach-to-consciousness)

Now I can only edit the question in order to answer comments - which is quite irritating. I'd like to know if there's a way to merge the two accounts so I'd be able to comment on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact the team for merging accounts, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) for details.

As explained there, visit https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts with this account and have the link/user number of the other account ready when doing so (in this case, the account number is 12597321 for the whole network and the user number on Philosophy.SE is 30235).

You will be requested to validate your identity.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I have no idea how I logged into it - the site only asked for a name iirc.

Comment: Oh - that's funny, apparently it signed me into the same email address :)

Comment: And now I lost 3 bronze badges during the merge process lol. Any chance I'll get them back or that's just nitpicking? - edit: I think I lost them because it was a confirmed post edit badges which are not what I did anymore as now I only edited the post as myself. Tricky :)

Comment: @YechiamWeiss I guess you lost one due to the confirmed edit, but I'd suggest being patient. Automatic recalculations are put into the server task list and may take some time for being processed.

Comment: thank you very much for the help.